# PIP doesn't install data_files to the right location

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

I would like to upload my package on Pypi and make it available via PIP. My package needs to install files under `/etc/` and `/usr/` (conf files and data files).

To achieve this goal I'm using the `data_files` property in `setup()`.

When I run the install via `python setup.py install` everything works great, my files are installed where I want.

But when I use PIP my files seems to be stuck under `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages` and I don't understand why. How can I install my files properly when using PIP?

My package is a networking tool and I need to install files under `/etc/network/` by default so I don't want the user to have to do anything else than `pip install my_package`

Env:

```
$ pip -V
pip 10.0.0 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="16.04.3 LTS (Xenial Xerus)"
ID=ubuntu
```

I've reduced the issue to a very simple setup.py file.

```
$ tree
.
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── my_package.conf
│   ├── my_package.py
│   └── test_file
└── setup.py

1 directory, 5 files
```

The problem is showing with both distutils and setuptools

```
$ cat setup.py
#!/usr/bin/env python

from distutils.core import setup
#from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my_package',
    version='1.0',
    description='Test package',
    author='Julien',
    author_email='julien@website.com',
    packages=['my_package'],
    data_files=[
        ('/tmp/', ['my_package/test_file']),
        ('/etc/my_package/', ['my_package/my_package.conf']),
        ('/usr/bin/', ['my_package/my_package.py'])
    ]
)
```

Here are some logs (first installing via `python setup.py install` then via pip and easy install):

```
$ ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
total 36K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  222 Apr 18 16:47 easy-install.pth
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 12:35 pip
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 12:35 pip-10.0.0.dist-info
$ ls /tmp/
$ ll /etc/my_package
ls: cannot access '/etc/my_package': No such file or directory
$ ll /usr/bin/my_package.py
ls: cannot access '/usr/bin/my_package.py': No such file or directory
$
$ python setup.py install
running install
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package
copying my_package/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package
copying my_package/my_package.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package
copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package/my_package.py -> /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package/__init__.py to __init__.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package/my_package.py to my_package.pyc
running install_data
copying my_package/test_file -> /tmp/
creating /etc/my_package
copying my_package/my_package.conf -> /etc/my_package/
copying my_package/my_package.py -> /usr/bin/
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/my_package-1.0.egg-info
$ python /usr/bin/my_package.py
hello world
$ ls /tmp/
  test_file
$ ll /etc/my_package
total 4.0K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 9 Apr 18 16:33 my_package.conf
```

See that it works great, now if I clean this up and try again using pip:

```
$ ll /etc/my_package
ls: cannot access '/etc/my_package': No such file or directory
$ python /usr/bin/my_package.py
python: can't open file '/usr/bin/my_package.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$
$
$ pip install . -v
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-s_jJG_
Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-install-gm_uo4
Processing /root/my_package
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-req-build-zDFQvX
  Running setup.py (path:/tmp/pip-req-build-zDFQvX/setup.py) egg_info for package from file:///root/my_package
    Running command python setup.py egg_info
    running egg_info
    creating pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info
    writing pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

    reading manifest file 'pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Source in /tmp/pip-req-build-zDFQvX has version 1.0, which satisfies requirement my-package==1.0 from file:///root/my_package
Could not parse version from link: file:///root/my_package
Building wheels for collected packages: my-package
  Created temporary directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-s5MYDt
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for my-package ...   Destination directory: /tmp/pip-wheel-s5MYDt
  Running command /usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-req-build-zDFQvX/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/pip-wheel-s5MYDt --python-tag cp27
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  installing to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  running install
  running install_lib
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package
  copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package/__init__.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package
  copying build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/my_package/my_package.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package
  running install_data
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package-1.0.data
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package-1.0.data/data
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/tmp
  copying my_package/test_file -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/tmp/
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/etc
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/etc/my_package
  copying my_package/my_package.conf -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/etc/my_package/
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/usr
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/usr/bin
  copying my_package/my_package.py -> build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/usr/bin/
  running install_egg_info
  running egg_info
  creating my_package.egg-info
  writing my_package.egg-info/PKG-INFO
  writing top-level names to my_package.egg-info/top_level.txt
  writing dependency_links to my_package.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
  writing manifest file 'my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found

  reading manifest file 'my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  writing manifest file 'my_package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
  Copying my_package.egg-info to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package-1.0.egg-info
  running install_scripts
  creating build/bdist.linux-x86_64/wheel/my_package-1.0.dist-info/WHEEL
done
  Stored in directory: /tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-s_jJG_/wheels/50/f9/70/af45a262303e11843fbd0173011769c87b1ae21d2f1f39bf42
  Removing source in /tmp/pip-req-build-zDFQvX
Successfully built my-package
Installing collected packages: my-package

Successfully installed my-package-1.0
Cleaning up...
$
$
$ python /usr/bin/my_package.py
python: can't open file '/usr/bin/my_package.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
$ ll /etc/my_package
ls: cannot access '/etc/my_package': No such file or directory
$
$
$
$
$ ll /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/
total 56K
-rw-r--r-- 1 root staff  195 Apr 18 17:04 easy-install.pth
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4.0K Apr 18 17:08 etc
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 18 17:08 my_package
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 18 17:08 my_package-1.0.dist-info
drwxr-sr-x 4 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 12:35 pip
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 12:35 pip-10.0.0.dist-info
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 16:47 testresources
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 17 16:47 testresources-2.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-sr-x 2 root staff 4.0K Apr 18 17:08 tmp
drwxr-sr-x 3 root staff 4.0K Apr 18 17:08 usr
$ tree /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/etc/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/etc/
└── my_package
    └── my_package.conf

1 directory, 1 file
$ tree /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/usr/
└── bin
    ├── my_package.py
    └── my_package.pyc

1 directory, 2 files
$ tree /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tmp/
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tmp/
└── test_file

0 directories, 1 file
$
```

with easy_install

```
$ easy_install . -v
Processing .
Writing /root/my_package/setup.cfg
Running setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /root/my_package/egg-dist-tmp-_2Ocor
error: Setup script exited with error: SandboxViolation: open('/tmp/test_file', 'wb') {}

The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.

This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the EasyInstall
maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is available.
```

I'm really stuck here and I'd be very grateful if someone could help me fix that! :)

Thanks!

Comment: *My package needs to install files under /etc/* Wrong approach and `pip` is not a suitable tool for that. Think e.g. someone installs the package with `pip install --user` or in a virtual environment under a user that doesn't have write-access to `/etc/`. If you want to install system files you have to use a proper distribution format (deb or rpm) and a proper installer (again, dpkg or rpm).